# Downtime when upgrading or restarting a node

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync, syncing

I run not only Cardano nodes but also Ethereum and other nodes.

I think the downtime is longer when upgrading or restarting a Cardano node compared to other nodes.
Downtime here is the time between when a node is restarted and when it starts synchronizing blocks again.
It took over an hour for Mainnet to start synchronizing.
It cannot be any other node.

I have three questions.

1. Why does it take so long for the Cardano node?
2. Is there any way to reduce the downtime?
3. Is there anything the community can do to improve downtime?

Best Regard!!
Any advice is welcome.

The specifications are as follows

- Cardano-node

  - CPU: 4
  - Memory: 16Gi
- Ogmios

  - CPU: 500m
  - Memory: 16Gi
- Postgres

  - CPU: 8
  - Memory: 32Gi
- GraphQL

  - CPU: 2
  - Memory: 4Gi
- DBSync

  - CPU: 4
  - Memory: 32Gi
- Hasura

  - CPU: 500m
  - Memory: 2Gi

Comment: How are you stopping the `node`? If the `node` is sent a `SIGTERM` the `node` will do a safe shutdown (I have seen this take up to 5 minutes) which results in a quicker restart (under 10 minutes in my experience). If the `node` does not shut down safely (or the safe shutdown did not complete) then startup will be longer. Also be aware that when there is a change in the on-disk storage format, a complete rebuild will be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  
I'm using ArgoCD to manage my nodes, but I don't shut them down and let them reboot or adapt to version changes without shutting them down.  
How do I do a safe shutdown?
Best Regard!! Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. you should ask the people who develop ArgoCD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best step is stopping the node correctly which can vary a bit on how you run the cardano-node

Another thing that I do is dump the ledger before rebooting
So I look at the current block. For example right now 72849870
Also you need to put the path to your ~/cardano-node/db/ledger (for my build for example)

The command then is as follows:
cardano-cli query ledger-state --mainnet --out-file ~/cardano-node/db/ledger/72849870

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try!